# Listview column problems

Tags: c#, listview, listbox, taskmanager

I have to a listbox and a listview, listbox is for viewing what programs are running listview is for filtering a specific process(I listed it in like chrome, mspaint, notepad etc.) when these programs are running "Status" column of listview would go "Active" and when one of these programs closes it goes inactive. My problem is whenever a program closes "Status" column stays "Active", how can I change it to "Inactive" when the program closes?

```
private void running_process()
    {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses("NAMEOFPC");
           // listView1.Items[0].SubItems.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
            {

                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add("Inactive");
                foreach (Process p in processes)
                {
                    if (listView1.Items[i].Text == p.ProcessName)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
                        listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = "Inactive";
                        for (int j = 0; j < listBox1.Items.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (listBox1.Items[j].ToString() == listView1.Items[i].Text)
                            {
                                // listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Clear();
                                listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = "Active";
                            }
                           else
                           {
                                   listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = "Inactive";
                           }
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
    }

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        running_process();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var processes = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (ListViewItem item in this.listView1.Items)
    {
        item.SubItems[1].Text = ((processes.Any(p => p.ProcessName == item.SubItems[0].Text)
                                    ? "ACTIVE"
                                    : "INACTIVE"));
    }
}
```

Comment: whats activeColumnIndex and processNameColumnIndex?

Comment: You are allowed to put some thought into it yourself you know.  Look at the code.  How are they being used?  `activeColumnIndex` is used as an index to get the subitem whose `Text` is being set to "ACTIVE" or "INACTIVE".  Hey!  Maybe it's the index of the Active column.  I'll let you work out what `processNameColumnIndex` is for yourself.

Comment: I've fixed the code.  `item` needs to be declared as type `ListViewItem` because the `Items` collection is not generic, hence type inference makes it type `Object`.  Also, I fixed my indexing to use brackets instead of parentheses, which are used in VB.

Comment: The code should be correct however I'm getting the error `A local variable named 'p' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'p', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else` the `p` after `myProcessArray.Any`

Comment: If you already have a variable named `p` in scope then use something other than `p` in the code I provided.

Comment: That said, the code I provided should replace your entire `for` loop and your `p` variable is declared inside it.  As such, you should only have one `p` variable anyway.

Comment: It still won't change to "INACTIVE". Did yours change when you run it?

Comment: I typed that code directly into the browser and may have missed a parenthesis but, other than that, it runs perfectly for me.  I just updated the code to exactly what I just tested.